# How to read and compute statistics on streaming data which is updated in file?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

I have streaming data which is updated in .txt file on my computer. Every second one reading is added on new line. I want to read this data as it arrives and compute statistics on this streaming data. I know how to handle offline data and compute statistics. But I stuck when data is streaming.

I want to use rolling window to determine if standard deviation of the data is below certain threshold value.

I am new to python, need help with this code.

This is what I wrote to read the file but I am not sure if it is correct or how to calculate rolling window standard deviation on  this streaming data.

```
datalist=[]
with open("data.txt") as file_data:

    for data in file_data:
        if not data:
            plt.pause(0.01)
            continue

        datalist.append(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Pandas.

With Pandas, you have the DataFrame and Series Data structures that contain functions like [`rolling.std()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) which can help you do exactly what you want.

Depending on your .txt file, you can open it in Pandas and add column names with

```
data = pd.read_csv('output_list.txt', header = None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "etc."]
```

(it may be different depending on your separator).

However, if you want to process this data in real time, you may need to consider using specific algorithms other than rolling window.